# Efficient Login to Facebook for Mobile Websites?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Using the [Facebook JavaScript Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/) is the classical way to go. I have no problem with that.

But, when I build a mobile website I don't want the user to download the Facebook all.js which is 174KB. It is fine on desktop but for mobile web it is far to big.

**Is there another way of doing facebook login without using the all.js?**

Answer (score 0):

The only other way of doing facebook login without using all.js is implement the login flow from the backend (for instance using the PHP sdk).
Doing this way you won't need to download any additional file from client side.

Unfortunately i can't see any other solutions using javascript.